# Counting number of times a group of string have occurred and print the string and number of occurrence in python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, counter

I am trying to read a text file line by line and check the number of occurrence of each group of strings in a line for example. A text file contains these lines (Which varies)

```
X_0_Gui_Menu_400_Menu_System
X_0_Gui_Menu_400_Menu_System
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_300_Menu_Outputs
X_0_Gui_Menu_300_Menu_Outputs
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
```

I would like to get an output of

```
X_0_Gui_Menu_400_Menu_System
2 times

X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
3 times

X_0_Gui_Menu_300_Menu_Outputs
2 times

X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
8 times
```

I saw some forums using count, but I dont know what data will be there in the file to give an input to check, but it is completely random. So I am confused how to implement this. Any guidance would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using the Counter container from the [collection module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). From the Python documentation: "A Counter is a dict subclass for counting hashable objects. It is an unordered collection where elements are stored as dictionary keys and their counts are stored as dictionary values. Counts are allowed to be any integer value including zero or negative counts. The Counter class is similar to bags or multisets in other languages."

Here is a sample code that does what you are asking for. I used the fact that a file is an iterator to create the Counter object. When you iterate, on a file it yields each line but does not remove the newline character so I used the strip() method to get the output you suggested.

```
filename = 'test.txt'

filetxt = """\
X_0_Gui_Menu_400_Menu_System
X_0_Gui_Menu_400_Menu_System
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
X_0_Gui_Menu_300_Menu_Outputs
X_0_Gui_Menu_300_Menu_Outputs
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
X_0_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
"""

with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(filetxt)

from collections import Counter
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    c = Counter(f)

# use iteritems() in python 2.7 instead of items
for key, value in c.items():
    print(key.strip())
    print('{:d} times'.format(value))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
file = open('test.txt')
fileLines = file.read().split('\n')
list = []

for line in fileLines :
    for tup in list:
        if tup[0] == line:
                list[list.index(tup)][1] = list[list.index(tup)][1] + 1
                break
    else:
        list.append([line, 1])

for s in list:
    print(s[0] + ' ' + str(s[1]))
```

This should read the lines in the file.
If the line does not exist in list, then it adds a tuple to the list consisting of the string and the count.
If the line does exist, then it just adds 1 to the count in the appropriate tuple.

Comment: Hi, I get an error while executing this function as     `print(s[0] + ' ' + s[1])
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects`

Comment: @VenkateshPadmanabhan Yeah, sorry. I didn't check my code. I just debugged it. It works now. Please try the updated code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply again,I tried the updated code. But still it doesn't work properly. `I just get string 0
 10_Gui_Menu_409_Menu_System_Sensor
 20_Gui_Menu_400_Menu_System
 50_Gui_Menu_000_Menu_root
 14_Gui_Menu_300_Menu_Outputs
 20_Gui_Menu_320_Menu_Outputs_SDI
 23_Gui_Menu_310_Menu_Outputs_EVF_mon
 10_Gui_Menu_312_Menu_Outputs_EVF_exptools
 20_Gui_Homescreen_Homescreen
 40_Gui_Homescreen_WB_Switchview
 50_Gui_Homescreen_WB_List
 1`
It doesn't give me the number of counts

Comment: I don't know to tell you. My output consists of the string followed by the number of times it appeared in the file.

I think in your 'test.txt' file, you put each string on the same line instead of new lines. Either move each string in the file to a new line, or on line 2 in the code, replace 'fileLines = file.read().split('\n')' with 'fileLines = file.read().split(' ')'