# Counting number of occurance of a string in python

Tags: python

This is question is based on the answer provided from here [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27045146/counting-number-of-times-a-group-of-string-have-occurred-and-print-the-string-an)

I want to count number of occurrence of a string from a text file, I have come up with the following with the help of a post linked above. But it doesn't work every time robustly under some situation.

The code:

```
def counter(filename):
    from collections import Counter
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        c = Counter(f)

    # use iteritems() in python 2.7 instead of items
    for key, value in c.iteritems():
        print("   > " + key.strip() + ': \033[1m\033[32m{:d} visit\033[0m'.format(value))
```

It works fine for this data

```
X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays
X_0_Gui_Menu_3231_Menu_Outputs_SDI_status
X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays
X_0_Gui_Menu_321_Menu_Outputs_SDI_processing
X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays
X_0_Gui_Menu_3231_Menu_Outputs_SDI_status
```

Which produces output like:

> X_0_Gui_Menu_3231_Menu_Outputs_SDI_status: 2 visit
>   X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays: 3 visit
>   X_0_Gui_Menu_321_Menu_Outputs_SDI_processing: 1 visit

But it doesn't work properly for the following input

```
"StatusInfoSet (2, 12)"
"StatusInfoSet (2, 44)"
"CenterMark (2, 2)"
"FrameSet (2, 0)"
"FrameSet (2, 1)"
"FrameSet (2, 0)"
"CenterMark (2, 1)"
"StatusInfo (2, 1)"
"StatusInfo (2, 0)"
"SurroundMask (2, 2)"
MediaCodec (3)
SetSensorFormat (1)
UserSwitchSet (99)
SetExIndex (10)
SetExIndex (11)
"EiSwitchAssign (1, 11)"
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
Hello
```

The output produced is :

```
   > Hello: 1 visit
   > Hello: 4 visit
   > SetSensorFormat: 1 visit
   > SetExIndex: 2 visit
   > : 1 visit
   > StatusInfoSet: 2 visit
   > SurroundMask: 1 visit
   > UserSwitchSet: 1 visit
   > EiSwitchAssign: 1 visit
   > MediaCodec: 1 visit
   > FrameSet: 3 visit
   > StatusInfo: 2 visit
   > CenterMark: 2 visit
```

Which is not exactly how I want it to work. As you can see `Hello` is mentioned two times though the count is correct, it also gives 1 visit to no data.

I would also like the code to arrange the visit in top from highest visit to lowest visit like:

> X_0_Gui_Menu_322_Menu_Outputs_SDI_overlays: 3 visit
>   X_0_Gui_Menu_3231_Menu_Outputs_SDI_status: 2 visit
>   X_0_Gui_Menu_321_Menu_Outputs_SDI_processing: 1 visit

It would be great to have some guidance about this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need strip your input items *before* counting; pre-process the lines in a generator expression to strip whitespace:

```
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    c = Counter(line.strip() for line in f if line.strip())
```

I'm also skipping *empty* lines. This can be expanded to extract more detailed information you want to count.

The highest-to-lowest sort is easy; just use the [`Counter.most_common()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```
for key, value in c.most_common():
    print("   > {}: \033[1m\033[32m{:d} visit\033[0m'.format(key, value))
```

This returns items sorted from highest to lowest.